# Maps of List in flutter

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Can I have your help please with my project?
How to create, send, and get these next data from firebase using flutter:

```
   ["20-12-07":[1,2,5],"20-12-08":[7,8,9],"20-12-09":[5,7,8]]
```

Where "20-12-07" is a date, and [1,2,5] is the index of an hour in this day (eg:1 is 00:00am, 2 is 00:01am, and so on).

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: static List<dynamic> blockTimes = [];
  static void generateBlocks() {
    DateTime day = DateTime.now();
    int hours = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        hours += 1;
        minutes = 0;
      } else {
        minutes = 30;
      }
      blockTimes.add({hours, minutes});
      if (hours == 23) break;
      print(blockTimes);
    }   I just have this function that generate the time blocks every half hour automatically

Comment: Please edit your question to include that code, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.